# How to deploy artifacts from S3 into tomcat using S3 and deploy plugin?

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, tomcat7

I have a Jenkins server doing builds and saving the artifacts to AWS S3 using job 1.  I'd like to now create a another job in Jenkins that will deploy those artifacts from S3 onto a tomcat server using deploy plugin.  I've got the S3 plugin installed and the deploy plugin installed.  I'm trying to parameterize my build so the user will select which build they want deployed.

I've added a build parameter Build Selector for Copy Artifact with name BUILD_SELECTOR.  Then in the build portion I have S3 Copy Artifact.  I specified the project name (Job 1), specified by build parameter with the parameter name BUILD_SELECTOR, artifact is myapp-1.0-$BUILD_SELECTOR.war, and target is $WORKSPACE.

But it doesn't work saying "Build #285[285] doesn't have any S3 artifacts uploaded".  However, I have a Publish Artifacts to S3 in a post build step in the other project.

What am I not doing correctly?  I can't find any information about using artifacts stored in S3.  All I can find is publish artifacts to S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the "Publish Artifacts to S3" plugin had to have "Manage Artifacts" checked.

I blogged about it in detail here: http://wrongnotes.blogspot.com/2015/05/jenkins-s3-copy-artifact-deploy-plugin.html